# Column prefix being added to a column from somewhere

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So basically I'm trying to update a row with a simple UPDATE statement:

`UPDATE course_periods SET teacher_id='284' WHERE course_period_id='3979' AND syear='2017';`

This will return as error:

`Unknown column 'ac.COURSE_PERIOD_ID' in 'where clause'`

Therefore I'm lost, where is this 'ac' prefix being added from? the column `course_period_id` exists in the table `course_periods`.

I've also tried doing aliases `UPDATE course_periods t1 SET t1.teacher_id'284' WHERE t1.course_period_id='3979'...`

I've also tried adding back quotes(`) to the table names but with no success.

[image for proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3K86.png)
(sorry for the language but I guess its pretty clear)

Comment: Try through some other tool or in CLI if you have the same error.

Comment: Tried through PHP first(PDO queries), got the same error

Comment: Then what is the relevance of phpMyAdmin tag in your question?

Comment: fixed, error was coming from a trigger, and yea, good question about phpmyadmin

Comment: triggers can be nasty buggers to debug, especially if a plain query is generating a trigger error..